# bash: wait doesn't seem to return

Tags: bash, signals, wait

I'm using the following wrapper around Postfix for running it in a Docker Container (Alpine 3.6 with bash and coreutils installed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Starts Postfix and waits for its master process to exit.

set -eo pipefail

MASTER_PID=

main() {
  # Start Postfix
  postfix start

  # Wait for Postfix to start
  while [ ! -f /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid ]; do sleep 1; done

  # Read the PID of Postfix's master process
  MASTER_PID=$(cat /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid | tr -d '[:space:]')
  readonly MASTER_PID

  # Wait for Postfix to exit
  tail -f /dev/null --pid "$MASTER_PID" &
  wait "$!"

  printf "Postfix Done\n"
}

shutdown() {
  printf "Stopping Postfix\n"
  # Stop Postfix
  postfix stop
}

# Add signal handlers for stopping Postfix
trap shutdown SIGINT SIGTERM

main
```

I'm using `tail` to wait for Postfix's master process to exit, since it's not a child of the shell executing the script. However, the `tail` process is and I'd expect `wait "$!"` to wait for tail to exit, which happens when Postfix's master process exits. This is necessary to allow signal handling and it seems to work: When sending `SIGTERM`, Postfix is stopped and the script terminates. However `Postfix Done` is never printed. What's the reason for that? Interestingly, when replacing `wait "$!"` with

```
TAIL_PID="$!"
while kill -0 "$TAIL_PID" 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done;
```

It works and `Postfix Done` is printed as expected.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `wait "$!"` with `wait`?

Comment: Yes, I was using that before, since it should be the same thing. The tail process is the only running child process. I replaced it with "$!", just to make sure.

Comment: What about removing `&` and `wait "$!"`?

Comment: Without those the signals will not be handled before tail exits, which never happens without the signal handler running "postfix stop". However I just checked the source of tail. It does a busy wait too, using sleep. So in fact I do not gain a thing by waiting for tail and could as well use the while sleep loop above.

Comment: `tail -f` never exits under normal circumstances.

Comment: @chepner Could you elaborate? By passing a PID it is supposed to exit when the PID exits (according to the man pages): "--pid: With -f, terminate after process ID, PID dies".

Comment: That's true. But `tail -f` runs *forever*, always waiting for more input from the file it is trailing. If `tail -f` never exits, then neither does the `wait` command that is waiting for `tail -f` to exit.

Comment: I verified that it indeed uses the correct PID and I expect it to exit accordingly when Postfix's master dies. Also, the while/sleep solution shouldn't work if tail ran forever. It is indeed the case that after sending SIGTERM to the process running the script above, there is no process left when checking with ps afterwards. Which is good and exactly what I want, but it's super strange that the printf is not executed.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)